# Import from npmcdn in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, angular, webstorm, systemjs

In my `systemjs.config.js` I have mapped `'@angular'` to `'https://npmcdn.com/@angular'` so I can import things like:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
```

but WebStorm produces an error `TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'`.

Is there any way to fix this other than downloading every module from https://npmcdn.com/@angular to some local directory?

Comment: Nope (at least from IDE side). https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206894029-Webstorm-does-not-understand-Angular-2- -- check last comment in particular

Comment: BTW -- this error is NOT produced by WebStorm -- but by some TS tool (compiler?) that is used by IDE to check the syntax etc. The `TS2307: ` reference clearly indicates that (IDE does not use error numbers/codes in own inspections).

Comment: It's sad, but thanks anyway. Clearly, if someone wish not to use npm he should be ready for a way full of pain.